# How can I play Ace of Spades?

Tags: windows, wine, games

There is a new awesome game called "[Ace of Spades](http://ace-spades.com/)", that is similar to Minecraft. However, it seems to be only available on Windows.

How can I play it under Ubuntu? Please answer with a  step by step guide if you manage to get it running.

---

Useful links for the hero to answer this question:

- [Game forums](http://ace-spades.com/forums/)
- [Guide](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/images/11/apr/spade/spade.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installation

- Go to the software center and install wine ([or by clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/wine))
- Go to [www.ace-spades.com](http://ace-spades.com/) or the download link listed above and download the installer.
- Double-clicking on the installer should just run it. If not, try right clicking and select "open with Wine" or "open with Wine Windows Program Loader".
- Let the installer run, it should just do everything automatically for you.

Running

RUNNING THE GAME:

Ace of Spades can connect to a server through one of two ways. The second method  is much more reliable and helps you get around the server problems that many users seem to experience.

- Install any windows web-browser through WINE. Go to [here](http://www.ace-spades.com)  and simply click on the server you want to join. The rest should work as normally under windows. This should be possible with a native Linux browser, but it involves setting the association between the browser and 'client.exe' manually and I haven't been able to get it to work just yet.
- Launch the program via command line: In a terminal(Press Ctrl + Alt + T) type `wine '/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Ace of Spades/client.exe' -aos://#######` Replace USER with your username and ###### with the server number you want to join. The server number can be found on www. Ace-spades. Com  by right clicking on a server name and choosing "Copy Link Location". This can be pasted to replace the entire aos: //##### argument.

[Source](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12965)

Comment: Hee hee, I wrote that. I was very confused when I saw this at first.

Answer (score 0):

You need wine. You can get it from software center.
More info here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23208&iTestingId=62800